# @media rule doesnt work on 600px but works on other values

Tags: css, firefox, media-queries

There is an `.element` that has `margin-right:40px`

I set the media rule to: `@media (max-width:600px) {.element{margin-right:0;}}`

The media rule will not trigger on `600px`, it triggers on `599px` (only on Firefox).

Now, if i change the above rule to this: `@media (max-width:753px) {.element{margin-right:0;}}`

then the rule will trigger at `753px` as it should. It seems like `600px` specifically is not triggering.

I have attached an image to showcase the issue:

[image: media query bug firefox]

As you can see we are at 600px and the margin-right value is active (yellow color).

What might be causing that bug?

More proof:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide HTML CSS code or any working link

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this in Firefox 96 with basic HTML and CSS. You must have other CSS rules which are overriding this rule. As Aman said, you need to provide code which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Check this link please: https://a13.gr/v3/blog/ - Open on firefox responsive, then go to 600px . You will not see the media rule showing up. After you change the responsive width to 599 you can suddenly see the media rule that it shows up. It is triggered on 599px instead of 600px. The element you should check is `.results-sin` @RichardDeeming

Comment: @dominotrix I can't reproduce the problem on that link - resizing to 600x947 shows the rule being applied as expected, and no `margin-right` on the element: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iebnG.png

Comment: Screenshot of the inspector: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvINI.png

Comment: I added 2 more images that might help you see the problem. The 600px media rule triggers only on 599px!

Comment: The weird thing is, if i make the media rule set to 599px it triggers on 599px and not on 598px as you might expect. It's as if this problem is only on 600px and only on Firefox.

Comment: I asked 2 of my friends to test it too on their PC and they said it works correctly, like yours @RichardDeeming . So i guess the problem is only on my Firefox.

Comment: I can't reproduce it in Firefox 96 or 97: [FF97 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0BZh.png) Do you have any add-ins installed?

Comment: Nope, none. I also use latest version. It's okay as long as it works good on other people.